# Wordpress REST API for user sign up (registration)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, user-registration, wordpress-rest-api

Is it possible to create a sign up form that can work through WP REST API for visitors to be able to create accounts on my site?

I can create such a form and use it to create new users. This works with wp_rest nonce when I am logged in as administrator.

But if there is a visitor which is not logged in, the same form does not work of course. I think this is a question of authentication. Can you suggest a general idea how this can work? How can I allow visitors to be able to sign up with REST API?

Comment: while WP doesn't provide this out of the box, there are plugins that can do this, and the 3rd party authentication plugins might provide solutions such as the OAuth 2 support. There's also a session management plugin at https://github.com/humanmade/rest-sessions that may be helpful by the same people who helped build the REST API

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you've found your answers already!

If not, just paste the following code in your theme's function.php, and it should work like a charm.The following code should add User Registration via REST API to your WordPress Website. It supports Registration of 'subscriber' and 'customer'. Source code also available on [Github](https://github.com/SK8-PTY-LTD/wp-rest-user).

Add it to your `function.php`

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wp_rest_user_endpoints' );

function wp_rest_user_endpoints() {
  /**
   * Handle Register User request.
   */
  register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'users/register', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler',
  ) );
}

/**
 * Register a new user
 *
 * @param  WP_REST_Request $request Full details about the request.
 * @return array $args.
 **/
function wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler( $request = null ) {
  $response = array();
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  $username = sanitize_user( $parameters['username'] );
  $email = sanitize_email( $parameters['email'] );
  $password = sanitize_text_field( $parameters['password'] );
  // $role = sanitize_text_field( $parameters['role']);

  $error = new WP_Error();
  if ( empty( $username ) ) {
    $error->add( 400, __( "Username field 'username' is required.", 'wp-rest-user' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    return $error;
  }
  if ( empty( $email ) ) {
    $error->add(401, __( "Email field 'email' is required.", 'wp-rest-user' ), array('status' => 400 ) );
    return $error;
  }
  if ( empty( $password ) ) {
    $error->add( 404, __( "Password field 'password' is required.", 'wp-rest-user' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    return $error;
  }
  // if (empty($role)) {
  //  $role = 'subscriber';
  // } else {
  //     if ( $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->is_role( $role ) ) {
  //      // Silence is gold
  //     } else {
  //    $error->add( 405, __("Role field 'role' is not a valid. Check your User Roles from Dashboard.", 'wp_rest_user' ), array('status' => 400 ) );
  //    return $error;
  //     }
  // }
  $user_id = username_exists( $username );
  if ( ! $user_id && email_exists( $email ) == false ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
      // Get User Meta Data (Sensitive, Password included. DO NOT pass to front end.)
      $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
      // $user->set_role( $role );
      $user->set_role('subscriber');
      // WooCommerce specific code
      if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        $user->set_role( 'customer' );
      }
      // Get User Data (Non-Sensitive, Pass to front end.)
      $response['code'] = 200;
      $response['message'] = sprintf( __( "User '%s' Registration was Successful", 'wp-rest-user' ), $username );
    } else {
      return $user_id;
    }
  } else {
    $error->add( 406, __( "Email already exists, please try 'Reset Password'", 'wp-rest-user' ), array( 'status' => 400 ));
    return $error;
  }
  return new WP_REST_Response( $response, 123 );
}
```

IMHO, a more better way would to include the additional function as a separate plugin. So even when your user changed theme, your api calls won't be affected.

Therefore I've developed a **plugin** for User Registration via REST API in WordPress. Better yet, it supports creating 'customer' for WooCommerce too!

[WP REST User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/), check it out if you want.

Comment: Hello @jack-song . please tell me why it returns $user_id instead of returning error when user_id exist? Is it ok to return error instead of $user_id (like Email error handling)?

Comment: Important! If you try to use this do not remove any of the checks as this could be a major security issue! This endpoint performs no password strength checks, and it doesn't even verify the email is an email! You can also exploit it to create 5000 users from a command line with something similar to this: `i=0; while [ $i -lt 5000 ]; do ((i++)); curl -X POST -d "username=test${i}&email=test${i}@example.com&password=test" http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/register; done` because there is no rate limiting or nonce checks

Comment: At a minimum I would suggest requiring the REST API nonce even if there is no cookie session to confirm the user has visited the site. I've made some edits to fix some issues such as an injection attack where the username was passed through the translation API and then directly into the response, and incorrect sanitising function, but this function is still unsafe!

Comment: How secure is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this two plugins for this:

WordPress JSON API plugin

and

JSON API User

These both plugins will help to get the job done.You will need nonce ID to call registration API,which will be given by plugin.

[this](http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-remotely-create-a-user-on-your-wordpress-website-using-json-api-request/) will explain , how it works!!

Comment: Thanks for the link! Helpful!