# WooCommerce Rest API for Login and Registration

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, native, wordpress-rest-api

I enable WooCommerce rest API and generate consumer_key and consumer_secret. I am developing a WooCommerce shop native mobile application. I do research for the WooCommerce rest API for My Account page login and registration form but can't see the solution. So if anyone has an idea about My Account page login and registration API then please suggest the solution for this.

Best regard,
Ketan.

Comment: Have you tried the default wordpress login?

Comment: @KelvinMariano no. Can you please explain more here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617707/wordpress-rest-api-for-user-sign-up-registration

Answer (score 3):

==> First install this https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/ plugin

==> **Registration API:**

1. Before the registration call, following API for New nonce generate:

   https://site_URL/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register
2. After that use following API for registration:

   https://site_URL/api/user/register/?username=john&email=john1@gmail.com&user_pass=123456789&nonce=HERE_INSERT_ABOVE_GENERATED_RANDOM_NONCE_STRING&display_name=username

==> **Login API:**

1. Insert the following code in your child theme functions.php file:

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );
    function register_api_hooks() {
      register_rest_route(
        'custom-plugin', '/login/',
        array(
          'methods'  => 'GET',
          'callback' => 'login',
        )
      );
    }
```

```
function login($request){
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $request["username"];
    $creds['user_password'] =  $request["password"];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
      echo $user->get_error_message();
    return $user;
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

2. After that use following API for login:

   https://site_URL/wp-json/custom-plugin/login?username=USERNAME_OR_EMAIL-ID&password=PASSWORD

Comment: Why you use "add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );" ? Please tell me about "custom_login" because you used only one time "custom_login" so where is the "custom_login" function ? I don't know about it so let me know please

Answer (score 0):

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' ); to add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'login' );

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).